# Convergence of $(a_n)$ when $(a_n^{1/n})$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that the sequence $(a_n^{1/n})$ converges. What is a sufficient condition that $(a_n)$ also converges? $a_n=n$ is an example of a divergent sequence such that $a_n^{1/n} = \sqrt [n] n$ converges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knowing the **existence** of the limit $\lim a^{1/n}$  is not much help when deciding whether $a_n$ has a limit.  For example, every sequence $a_n$ that is bounded between two positive numbers, $$0<m\le a_n\le M<\infty\quad \forall n$$
satisfies $a_{n}^{1/n}\to 1$. So do many unbounded sequences.

If you know **the value** of the limit $L=\lim a_n^{1/n}$, then you can say something:

- if $L<1$, then $a_n\to 0$
- if $L>1$, then $a_n\to\infty$

Either thing can happen when $L=1$.

Comment: (and many things not mentioned can happen when $L=1$)

Answer (score 0):

this is the cauchy criterion for the sequence

[image]